# PHP return a list of all the variables in a body of text that match a pattern

Tags: php, arrays

I have a body of text like so:

> Lorem Ipsum %final_walk_through_date% is simply dummy text of the
>   printing and typesetting industry. %buyer_full_name% Lorem Ipsum has
>   been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
>   unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
>   specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
>   leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
>   was popularised  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
>   containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
>   Ipsum %buying_side_commission_percent%. %escrow_officer_first_name%
>   and %ccrs_date%.

I want to use PHP to scan through this body of text and look for any variable that has this pattern %variable_name% and then add that value to an array.

In the end I would have an array that looks like so:

```
array[
     '%final_walk_through_date%',
     '%buyer_full_name%',
     '%buying_side_commission_percent%',
     '%escrow_officer_first_name%',
     '%ccrs_date%'
]
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `preg_match_all()` :

```
preg_match_all('~%\w+%~', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => %final_walk_through_date%
    [1] => %buyer_full_name%
    [2] => %buying_side_commission_percent%
    [3] => %escrow_officer_first_name%
    [4] => %ccrs_date%
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats basically exactly what [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is for:

```
$s = "Lorem Ipsum %final_walk_through_date% is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. %buyer_full_name% Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum %buying_side_commission_percent%. %escrow_officer_first_name% and %ccrs_date%.";

preg_match_all('/%[^%]*%/', $s, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/Rvc5n

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without regex too.
You can use explode and explode on % and array items with spaces are **not** variables.

```
$str = "Lorem Ipsum %final_walk_through_date% is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. %buyer_full_name% Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum %buying_side_commission_percent%. %escrow_officer_first_name% and %ccrs_date%.";
$arr = explode("%", $str . " "); 
// Adding space to end of string to make sure it removes last part if it's not a variable
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($v){
    If(strpos($v, " ") === false) return $v;
});

var_dump($newArr);
```

If you need to reset the array index you can use array_values to make it count from 0 again.

https://3v4l.org/909Zd

---

mickmackusa version of it:

```
$str = "%start_of_input% Lorem Ipsum %final_walk_through_date% is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. %buyer_full_name% Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum %buying_side_commission_percent%. %escrow_officer_first_name% and %ccrs_date%.";
$arr = explode("%", " " . $str . " ");
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($v){
    return strpos($v, " ")===false ? true : false;
});

var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: Please remove `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` and `$k`.  you aren't using them.  `array_filter()` is only really interested in`return`ing `true`/`false` and a `return` should be provided regardless of conditional outcomes. You need to prepend a space to `$str` before `explode`ing in case the first word is `%`-wrapped.  My recommended changes are here: https://3v4l.org/p2Mph

Comment: The prepend is not needed in my way of returning. Try it out and you will see. In your method you need it but not in mine. But the other is valid points, thanks!

Comment: The prepending is necessary if it is possible to have a %-wrapped substring at the start of the string.  That is the reason that I modified the input data--to display the fringe case.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  I should have set it up with a quotation mark or other punctuation at the start -- one or more characters not followed by space before `%`.  The effect that needs to be covered is the spoofing of a word boundary character in regex.   That is the reason for adding a space at the front and back of `$str`.  https://3v4l.org/TqNrl  Your code accommodates one fringe case but not the other -- though they are the same type of fringe case.

Comment: @mickmackusa *Your code accommodates one fringe case but not the other* Not sure if I agree with that. In general, how often do you start a string with a punctuatuion or quotation mark compared to with a normal letter? This is not a case of my code only works in on case, you made it break in one specific case. You can find such cases in all codes. If we use math in the string all possible solutions will break. `x=(100*50%)-(250*25%)` this string in both regex and explode will make it fail. https://3v4l.org/GCBns . There is no code that is failsafe when it comes to parsing.